# T-SQL C# CLR Execute permissions being lost on assemblies when are redeployed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, deployment, sql-server-data-tools, sqlclr

I have inherited a VS2015 .NET C# project that deploys C# assemblies as CLR stored procedures to SQL Server 2016. It has worked seamlessly for many years.

However recently I've noticed that when I redeploy (a.k.a "Publish Database"), one of the assemblies seems to lose `EXECUTE` permissions for one of the users.

Is there a way I can have the project reapply the `EXECUTE` permissions after it has redeployed? The script would have to know which SQL Server instance and database I'm deploying the updated CLR to. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what your publish step involves, but `alter assembly` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-assembly-transact-sql) should preserve permissions. Side note: SQLCLR is ... increasingly unpopular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User are never given execute permissions to an assembly. I suspect you are meaning execute permissions to one (or more)of the SQLCLR stored procedures that reference code within this assembly. You can fairly easily add a post-release T-SQL script to your Visual Studio project that will get included in the publish scripts (by SSDT via VS). In this T-SQL script you just add the `GRANT` statement. And, if it only makes sense in one particular database / instance, then you can wrap that `GRANT` statement in an `IF` block that checks for the current instance and/or database names.

Steps for adding a post-release script in VS 2015:

1. Select project in Solution Explorer
2. Go to "Project" menu
3. Select "Add New Item..."
4. Select "SQL Server" -> "User Scripts"
5. Select "Post-Deployment Script"
6. Type a name for the script down in the "Name:" field
7. Click the "Add" button
8. Edit the new SQL script to add the `GRANT` statement(s)

The contents of that script will be added to the end of any *deployment* / *publish* script generated by VS / SSDT, and hence will execute in every DB in which you execute those scripts.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I do mean Execute permissions on one of the SQLCLR stored procedures. How do you add a add a post-release T-SQL script? I need one that executes on whichever server and database the "Publish" is done to. Thanks

Comment: @andyabel I have updated my answer to include those instructions. Please review.